# Dynamic Allocation of 2d Array, pointers. filling, printing

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

i am trying to dynamically allocate and manipulate a 2D array, using pointers. I am new to pointers, so when i run this program it gives "Segmentation fault". What is the problem here ?

I used also (grid + i*c + j) with one asterisk , still doesn't work

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

float* DynamicAll(int row,int col){
    float *arr = (float *)malloc(row*col*sizeof(float));
    return arr;
}

void fillIn(float **grid, int r, int c){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < r ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < c; i++){
            **(grid + i*c + j) = i+j;
        }
    }
}

void print(float **grid, int r, int c){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < r ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < c; i++){
            printf("%f  ", **(grid + i*c + j));
        }
    }
}
  
int main() { 
   int row = 3, col = 3; 
   float *arr;
   arr = DynamicAll(row,col);
   fillIn(&arr,row,col);
   print(&arr,row,col);
   free(arr); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: 'for(int j = 0 ; j < c; i++){'  !!

Comment: Bad debug fail - if you had printffed out the indices, you would have spotted that 'j' does not change:((

Comment: You can thank me by learning how to do basic debugging before developing any more apps, (use of gdb, maybe:)

Comment: okay, i will start

Comment: If you are using Windows, you could download Codeblocks. Comes with gcc and gdb pre-installed and the debugger is fairly easy to use. Quite newbie-friendly overall, at least as far as professional tool chains go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the double-pointer (pointer to pointer) that you pass to and us in the `fillIn` and `print` functions. That's wrong, totally wrong.

Or well, it could be used, but then you need to dereference the pointer `grid` in those function *first*, before you do pointer arithmetic on it.

But I don't see any reason to do that, so just pass the pointer `arr` as-is to the function (and modify it accordingly:

```
// Note only single pointer here
//                v
void fillIn(float *grid, int r, int c){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < r ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < c; i++){
            // Only single dereference here
            *(grid + i*c + j) = i+j;
        }
    }
}

...

// Not using the address-of operator here
fillIn(arr, row, col);
```

---

If, for some unknown reason, you insist on keeping the pointer to pointer then you must dereference the pointer first:

```
*(*grid + i*c + j) = i+j;
```

Notice the placement of the two asterisks, and how one is used to dereference the pointer `grid` and the other dereference the calculated pointer.

Also note that for *any* pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. That means the expression is equal to:

```
(*grid)[i*c + j] = i+j;
```

Now it might also be easier to see what was wrong with your original expression.

Just for clarity, your original expression was equal to this:

```
grid[i*c + j][0] = i+j;
```

Comment: Actually i want to have pointer to pointer, thats why i used **grid, how can i dereference the pointer grid in thoise functions pls ?

Comment: @UglyMicha `for(int j = 0 ; j < c; i++)` See something wrong in that loop? (Credit to Martin James)